# Unable to find column position by name: accountid [The column name uniqueId is not valid.] [n/a]]

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Azure SQL database that I'm trying to map via JPA. Many of the tables have a uniqueidentifier column. I'm trying to map them like so:
Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[c_testTable]
(
    id TINYINT NOT NULL,
    accountid uniqueidentifier not null,
    statcode INT not NULL,  
    statcodename VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    recordcount int null, 
    CONSTRAINT [c_testTable] PRIMARY KEY (accountid,statcode,id) 
) 



@Entity
@Table(name = "c_testTable")
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(TestEntityKeys.class)
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    .......
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "statcode")
    private String statcode;
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "uuid2", parameters = {})
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Id  
    @Column(name = "accountid", columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
    private String accountid;
......

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class TestEntityKeys {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ....
    private int id;
    private String accountid;
    ......


    
}
```

I do get error-
Unable to find column position by name:
accountid [The column name accountid is not valid.] [n/a]]
so where is am going wrong?

Comment: `TestEntityKeys` is missing `String statcode`.